# Is there a sensible way to pickle forms in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to pickle a form in Django.  This is so that I can call that same point down the line from another web page.  However, I'm getting an error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function paginator_number at 0x0000020BD0CBE840>: it's not the same object as django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list.paginator_number
```

Since pickle can't handle functions.  Is there a workaround or alternative approach that's preferable?  I'm wondering if it's just bad practice to pickle a form.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue when I had to cache and restore the form state. The culprit was the `renderer` attribute of the form and several of its properties, such as `form._errors` (see [the form rendering API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/renderers/) for more context).

My workaround was to register a custom pickle handler for the `django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates` renderer so that it wouldn't save any state when pickling. On unpickling, the object is re-created from scratch.

```py
import copyreg

from django.forms.renderers import DjangoTemplates

def pickle_django_templates(instance):
    return DjangoTemplates, ()


copyreg.pickle(DjangoTemplates, pickle_django_templates)
```